# jQuery Masonry breaking randomly at certain widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using jQuery Masonry to develop a responsive grid of photos. I'm using a simple CSS proportional grid, and everything works fine (other than the fact that floats don't work vertically). The moment I add masonry this layout breaks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // select container
    var $work   = $(".work");

    // set columns based on window width
    var columns = 3,
        setColumns = function() { columns = $(window).width() > 768 ? 3 : 2; };

    $work.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $work.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.project',
            columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
                return containerWidth / columns;
            }
        });

        $(window).on('resize', function() {
                    // set columns now that the browser width is different.
            setColumns();
            $work.masonry('reload');
        }).resize();
    });
});
```

A jsfiddle demonstrating the issue can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Exh9N/3/).

Above the 768px breakpoint, things work (albeit with lots of flickering), but below the break point what should be two columns only fits into one.

Fixes I've tried:

- Setting columnWidth to 1 fixes it in Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome.
- Setting the width of one of the columns to 47.5% instead of 49% (which accounts for one 2% margin), but then my grid doesn't line up visually.

I suspect it's something to do with widths and margins being ever so slightly over, but I've checked my code thoroughly and the numbers should add up to a nice even 100% width. It's only when Masonry comes in that it breaks.

Thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd not seen Masonry before. Thank you for making such a solid case against it! Sarcasm aside, this would be pretty easy in Twitter Bootstrap, have you evaluated the two products side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the margins to 0 and the masonry should fit it all together.  Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/uMgwm/1

```
/* basic grid structure */
 .half, .third, .two-third, .quarter {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
    .two-third + .third, .third:nth-child(3n+0), .quarter:nth-child(4n+0) {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    .half:nth-child(2n+0), .third:nth-child(3n+0), .quarter:nth-child(3n+0) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Haha. Thought I tried that. It's causing an issue when lining up with the full width photo, but that can be fixed by setting 'width: 98%' instead. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  You can also use the masonry gutter options.  http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#gutterwidth